# Error Java en android Replication failed, request pending true java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled

Tags: java, android

no entiendo muy bien que es lo que esta pasando, luego de relizar una consulta a una base de datos Firestore, comenezo a aparecer la siguient excepción la cual no entiendo.

```
2020-04-01 12:24:17.412 25112-8356/? E/Finsky: [678] phu.a(3): Replication failed, request pending true
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
    at apcg.a(PG:2)
    at apcg.get(PG:11)
    at apfa.a(PG:1)
    at apdw.a(PG:20)
    at apds.run(PG:3)
    at kcj.execute(PG:1)
    at apcg.b(PG:20)
    at apcg.a(PG:16)
    at apcg.a(PG:36)
    at apck.run(PG:3)
    at apeh.run(Unknown Source:7)
    at kcj.execute(PG:1)
    at apei.execute(PG:1)
    at apde.b(PG:1)
    at apde.a(PG:3)
    at aped.done(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.cancel(FutureTask.java:181)
    at apdo.cancel(Unknown Source:4)
    at kdb.cancel(Unknown Source:2)
    at pil.a(PG:19)
    at pil.a(PG:24)
    at phz.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at kcg.run(Unknown Source:14)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Les agradezco desde ya su ayuda!

Comment: nunca he probado firestore pero puede ser un problema de concurrencia... ¿Estás accediendo a Firestore en el hilo principal? Si es así, debes cambiarte a uno secundario, ya que las operaciones de Entrada/Salida son costosas para el sistema y pueden bloquear la UI.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to to inflate a layout on the main activity on an element which is not there.Cross  Check your xml layout

Comment: Please answer only in spanish, because you're at SO en español

Comment: Okay its showing in english on my browser. I dont know spanish but i have the answer